# How to use CommandLineRunner in Spring to test JPA entities?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2(two) entities Account and SocialService.
Account can have 1(one) service(logically), but SocialService can have many Accounts.
So i have Account class:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
@Data
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "social_service_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SocialService socialService;

    @Column(name = "service_link")
    private String serviceLink;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Account account = (Account) o;
        return id.equals(account.id) &&
                email.equals(account.email) &&
                password.equals(account.password) &&
                socialService.equals(account.socialService);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, email, password, socialService);
    }
}
```

and SocialService class

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "social_services")
@Data
public class SocialService {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "official_link")
    private String officialLink;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "accounts_social_service",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "social_service_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    )
    private List<Account> accounts;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        SocialService that = (SocialService) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equals(name, that.name) &&
                Objects.equals(officialLink, that.officialLink);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, officialLink);
    }
}
```

I try to test it with CommandLineRunner:

```
       @Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final SocialServiceRepository socialServiceRepository;
    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public DatabaseLoader(SocialServiceRepository socialServiceRepository, AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.socialServiceRepository = socialServiceRepository;
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Account account1 = new Account();
        Account account2 = new Account();
        List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();

        account1.setId(1L);
        account1.setEmail("1@gmail.com");
        account1.setPassword("123");
        account1.setServiceLink("https://stackoverflow.com");

        account2.setId(2L);
        account2.setEmail("2@gmail.com");
        account2.setPassword("345");
        account2.setServiceLink("https://stackoverflow.com");

        SocialService socialService = new SocialService();
        account1.setSocialService(socialService);
        account2.setSocialService(socialService);

        socialService.setId(1L);
        socialService.setName("stackoverflow");
        socialService.setOfficialLink("https://stackoverflow.com");

        accountList.add(account1);
        accountList.add(account2);
        socialService.setAccounts(accountList);

        accountRepository.save(account1);
        accountRepository.save(account2);
        socialServiceRepository.save(socialService);
    }
}
```

But I am getting empty table `account_social_service`
Where is mistake: in entity classes? Or in hardcode?

Updated: added full code

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add your accounts to accountList. Also, use ManyToOne in Account. As you're using JoinTable, do not use JoinColumn in Account.

So you'll have:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) private SocialService socialService;

@OneToMany @JoinTable( name = "accounts_social_service", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "social_service_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id") ) private List<Account> accounts;

Account account1 = new Account();
Account account2 = new Account();
account1.setId(1L);
account1.setEmail("1@gmail.com");
account1.setPassword("123");
account1.setServiceLink("https://stackoverflow.com"); 
account2.setId(2L);
account2.setEmail("2@gmail.com");
account2.setPassword("345");
account2.setServiceLink("https://stackoverflow.com");
SocialService socialService = new SocialService(); 
account1.setSocialService(socialService);
account2.setSocialService(socialService);
socialService.setId(1L);
socialService.setName("stackoverflow");
socialService.setOfficialLink("https://stackoverflow.com");
List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
accountList.add(account1);
accountList.add(account2);
socialService.setAccounts(accountList);
accountRepository.save(account1);
accountRepository.save(account2);
socialServiceRepository.save(socialService);
```

Comment: oh rly... But when i add to list account, I am getting error:
```Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'account_saver.accounts_social_service' doesn't exist```
```Error executing DDL "alter table accounts_social_service drop foreign key FKnv4qpalyk3rdmp4irddkb7gy2" via JDBC Statement```

Comment: why i have to do ManyToOne? If I need 1 account to 1 soc. serv ...?

Comment: I changed on ManyToOne - still errors 
```Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'account_saver.accounts_social_service' doesn't exist```
and ```org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table accounts_social_service drop foreign key FKclhqynxs5ilyubt1qgo0810ec" via JDBC Statement
```

Comment: Are you asking hibernate to create your tables? Drop it first because of old keys

Comment: I have create-drop in properties

Comment: @andrew17 because you can have many accounts to the same service

Comment: still ```GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table accounts drop foreign key FKmmnc0y0t9rxodp9hmh5d0d86u" via JDBC Statement```

Comment: i`ve added everything you said.

Comment: @andrew17 drop all tables and constraints before trying. As the error message is saying, it is trying to alter your schema. So you didn't drop it. And check if your user has the required permissions

Comment: But I say, my database is empty now...
```Unable to find model.Account with id 2```

Comment: After executing what?

Comment: @Table(name = "accounts"), @Table(name = "social_services")
is it correct names for that relation fields

Comment: No problem with your table name. Add your full code

Comment: trace without full commented code from with inserting data:https://pastebin.com/RmxCXdZ2

trace with this class: https://pastebin.com/byGJUrkk

Comment: No ideas?) because i cant understand... its strange

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the setId from all entities, since you specified a generation strategy.

I tested your code here and it is working properly with:

Mapping in account:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private SocialService socialService;
```

Mapping in social service:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "accounts_social_service",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "social_service_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
)
private List<Account> accounts;
```

Main:

```
    Account account1 = new Account();
    Account account2 = new Account();
    account1.setEmail("1@gmail.com");
    account1.setPassword("123");
    account1.setServiceLink("https://stackoverflow.com"); 
    account2.setEmail("2@gmail.com");
    account2.setPassword("345");
    account2.setServiceLink("https://stackoverflow.com");
    SocialService socialService = new SocialService(); 
    account1.setSocialService(socialService);
    account2.setSocialService(socialService);
    socialService.setName("stackoverflow");
    socialService.setOfficialLink("https://stackoverflow.com");
    accountRepository.save(account1);
    accountRepository.save(account2);
```

But, maybe it would be better not to use JoinTable in this case. Just put a JoinColumn in account (as it is OneToMany):

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "social_service")
private SocialService socialService;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "socialService")
private List<Account> accounts;
```

Comment: But i am hardcoding data, earlier i always did like that with setId)
Its strange

Comment: Thanks, i`ll try. But why not JoinTable? Is it not better to isolate data about what accounts has social service. It will be easier to count for example, how much accounts has single service.